# Update only with a REST API (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm currently using the API from Microsoft which is used to update firewall rules for azure sql servers. But I want to create the request so that it only updates existing firewall rules instead of also being able to create a new one.

For reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2020-08-01-preview/firewallrules/createorupdate

I am not sure if any code samples are required?

Comment: what have you tried now?

Comment: Can you share more details on this?

Comment: I got it working, first run a get request on the submit which checks whether or not the firewall rule exists and if it does then the put request is run. @LeonYue

Comment: Hi @CloudCDXX, so glad to hear the good news. I help you post it as answer. Hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: It's customary, if you post an answer that just quotes somebody else, to mark it as a community wiki post.

Comment: Hi @CloudCDXX,  if you don't want to accept it, you also can post by yourself. I will help vote it.  thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @LeonYue sorry for the late reply, I marked it as an answer, hope it does help someone else who might have the same task at hand! Thanks for the help! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CloudCDXX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13769987/cloudcdxx) posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67161696/update-only-with-a-rest-api-asp-net-mvc/67180086#comment118743507_67161696) saying:

> I got it working, first run a get request on the submit which checks
> whether or not the firewall rule exists and if it does then the put
> request is run.